# Service now attachments are not showing up

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm using service now api https://xyz.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file api for attaching files to the incidents. Files are getting attached to the incident in activity section but not showing up in the Manage Attachments section. How do I resolve the issue?

I'm using Rest API explorer to attach files to incidents. But I do not see them in below Manage Attachments section.[image]

I can only see them in activity
[image]

Rest API explorer that I'm using
[image]

Comment: Is this on the service portal, or the normal UI?

Comment: I'm attaching files through rest api explorer from the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it on my instance and it worked just fine. Please refer to the screen shot below and make sure that you have filled all the required fields 
[image]

and the record looks like following:
[image]

Comment: I had it working with the table name 'x_fru_inc_incident' instead of 'incident'. I'm not sure why.

Comment: `'x_fru_inc_` indicates a scoped application. You can check in `System Definition > Tables`